# Variable Defined by Input

Tags: c, variables

I'm quite new to C and I was wondering if it is possible to have a variable be defined by an input by the user. I've made a simple prime number counter which shows all the prime numbers from 1 to 100 and I was wondering if there is a library or a code which allows me to define a variable by the user input. [Here's my code for better understanding.](https://ideone.com/6NuxDi)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < 101; i++) { //I would want the "101" to be a user defined variable
        for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                printf("%d\n", i);
            }
            else if (i%j == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google argc(argument count) & argv(argument vector)

Comment: Do you want to get your input from the command line or by displaying a prompt to the user?

Comment: Learning C by trial&error or questions about very specific, particular issues is a really bad idea. Reading a commaon line argument or reading from `stdin` is explained in every beginner's C book.

Comment: As others mentioned, argv should be used for passing in input strings, and argc should be used to count/validate number of input string that your code expects as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int num;
   scanf("%d",&num); //to take a user input
 for (int i=2; i<=num; i++) //I would want the "101" to be a user defined variable
 {
  for (int j=2; j<=i; j++)
  {
    if (i == j)
      printf("%d\n",i);
    else if (i%j == 0)
      break;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using user input in this way is possible.  (It had better be possible!  Virtually all programs work on user input.)

In general, there are two main ways of doing it.  (1) read from the command line.  (2) read from a "file" -- which might just be the user's keyboard.

Let's look at both of these in turn.

## 1. Read from the command line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 int max;
 if(argc <= 1)
 {
  fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s max\n", argv[0]);
  exit(1);
 }
 max = atoi(argv[1]);
 for (int i=2; i<max; i++)
 {
  for (int j=2; j<=i; j++)
  {
    if (i == j)
      printf("%d\n",i);
    else if (i%j == 0)
      break;
  }
 }
}
```

To read from the command line, we declare `main` with two arguments: `argc` and `argv`.  When `main` gets called, `argc` will be a count of how many arguments there are, and `argv` will contain those arguments.  `argv` is an array of strings, or more precisely, an array of pointers to `char`, or `char *`.  Also, the first argument will always be the name of the program.

We want the user to type

```
name_of_the_program 200
```

to print primes up to 200.  So we make sure that the user typed at least one argument, that is, we complain if `argc` isn't at leaast 2: one for the name of the program, 1 for the argument the user typed.  Assuming the user *did* type an argument, it'll be in `argv[1]`.  (`argc[0]` is the program name.)  The command-line arguments are always passed as strings, but we want a number, an `int`.  So we call `atoi` to convert the string on the command line (like `"200"`) to an `int` (like `200`).

## 2. Read from a file.

In this case, the "file" we're going to read from is `stdin`, the standard input, which by default is the user's keyboard.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
 int max;
 char input_line[100];
 printf("How high to go? "); fflush(stdout);
 fgets(input_line, 100, stdin);
 max = atoi(input_line);
 if(max == 0)
 {
  fprintf(stderr, "try typing a number next time\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 for (int i=2; i<max; i++)
  ...
```

We print a prompt to tell the user what we need him to type.  We call

```
 fgets(input_line, 100, stdin);
```

to read one line of input -- that is, we expect the user to type some stuff, then hit RETURN.  Since we declared `input_line` to be an array of 100 characters, it's important that we tell `fgets` how big it is, so that `fgets` can be sure not to put more than 100 characters into the array.  (That could happen if the user, just to be ornery, typed 100 or more characters before hitting RETURN.)

Similarly to the command line case, we've read `input_line` as a line of text, a string.  So we call `atoi` again, to convert that string to an `int`.  Also, we make sure that the number is not 0.  If the user types "abc" or something, that isn't even a number, `atoi` will return 0, and we catch that, since we'd never want to try to print prime numbers up to 0.

[P.S. As an alternative to the `fgets` plus `atoi` technique I've presented here, another popular method is the `scanf` function (as illustrated, in fact, in another answer to this question).  You can use `scanf`, and it even seems pretty easy at first, but in the long run it's harder, and there are a bunch of things it doesn't handle at all well.  So I recommend learning how to use `fgets` and friends as soon as you can.]

Comment: If no argument is provided on the command line, your first example could default to `100` as the limit (or any other suitable value), rather than demanding an argument.  Both approaches are legitimate — it depends on what the program is used for.